# Use Regex in Java to split up topleveldomains that are stored in a variable

Tags: java, regex

I'm currently working on a system for a game, to prevent publicity from other servers.

I have come up with some RegEx, that allowed me to block a lot of publicity, but these **** keep adapting of course. They are using domains of their servers, that consist of things like "builder.de", "myserver.com" ad stuff, paired with some promises.

In order to track them, I think the only way is to get a decent filter for the domains, since they can endlessly change their promises, but buying expensive domains will at least strongly annoy them. We have gotten so quick in blocking domains, that they seem to rather find ways to sneak through our filter.

Now they have come up with a new thing, posting domains like this: "builder . *d*e". My Preprocessing of the message turns it into "builder d e". My blocked domains and topleveldomains are stored in two lists of strings, and I iterate over them:

```
public static boolean checkForAdverts(String check) {
    check = preprocessString(check);

    for (String domain : DataManager.domains) {
        for (String topleveldomain : DataManager.topleveldomains) {
            if (DataManager.isPairInWhitelist(domain, topleveldomain)) continue;
            if (CENSORED) { //Sorry, in case smb of these people find this post...
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have this variable `tldomain`, that contains `"de"`, but I want to allow one other character in it. If I was dealing with a plain up string, I would just have done `"d(.)?e"`, but that is impossible, since I never know what is inside my `tldomain`. Also, these toplevel-domains may consist out of three letters as well, e.g. `"com"`. I want to get a match if there is 1 or 2 character "hidden" somewhere in my toplevel-domain.

So I want:

Matches: "de" "dee" "dxe" "d e", or "coom" "com" "cxom" "cdom" "c om" "co m" "c o m"

I have no Idea how to do that if my toplevel-domain is stored in a variable, how can I do that?

Comment: Quite frankly, those matches don't have a real pattern. Regex, a pattern matcher, isn't going to be the best thing to use.

Comment: I had to read your question like 5 times and possibly suffered half of a stroke but are you simply asking "How do I detect spam domains in random text and block/remove them?"

Comment: Basically, it's about creating a regex from a string in a variable, when the contents and length are unknown to a certain parameter

Comment: @MichaelBianconi They match "d(.)?e" and "c(.)?o(.)?m". but I don't know how to introduce that to a string where I don't know the contents and length from :c